# Не работает удаление сессии

Tags: php, сессия

При логине создается куки с айди пользователя, создается сессия, редиректы работают на верные страницы, но выход работает только со страницы lkteacher.
Редирект проходит на логин, но тут же снова редиректит на страницу lkstudent.
Код логина, функции логаута приведен ниже

Не могу понять почему сессия не заканчивается и перекидывает на страницу lkstudent, без повторного ввода данных

```
class Model_Login extends Model{
    public function get_data()
    {
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'necodewars');

        $login = $_POST['login'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `login`='$login'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

        if(!$result){
            return 'Неверный логин';
        } else {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            if($password == $row['password']){
                if($row['admin_status'] == 1) {
                    session_start();
                    setcookie('user_id', $row['id']);
                    $this->redirect('/lkteacher');
                } elseif ($row['admin_status'] == 0) {
                    session_start();
                    setcookie('user_id', $row['id']);
                    $this->redirect('/lkstudent');
                }
            } else {
                return 'Неверный пароль';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код функции выхода:

```
    public function logout() {
        session_start();
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        return header('Location: http://necodewars/login');
    }
```

Comment: В показанном здесь коде вы никак не используете сессию, соответственно её удаление ни на что не влияет

Comment: А ещё у вас здесь целых три уязвимости, использование этого кода крайне опасно

Comment: это просто курсовая работа и код написанный на коленке, я прекрасно понимаю, что он кривой, но я планировала его дописывать после того, как справлюсь с проблемой в сессиях. Сессия создается при логине, но не удаляется при логауте, поэтому суть комментария про то, что сессии я не использую, я немного не уловила

Comment: То, что вы создаёте сессию, тоже ни на что не влияет, потому что вы всё равно никак её не используете. А вот почему вам очистка кук вдруг не помогает — загадка